# Resize object and parent objects based on child dimensions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, dimensions

I have the following Illustrator drawing of an iPad. The red box is set to be 176x235 pixels and I want to resize it up to 768x1024 pixels and have the the iPad container resize with it.

How can I make it so that resizing the red box object, the objects around it also resize with it (without selecting them as well) i.e. act as though they are locked to the red box.[image]

I basically want to be able to do a transform on that red box and type in its new dimensions and the rest of the objects follow it.. is this possible?

You can download the .ai file here to see how it looks: http://dev.driz.co.uk/hero-ipad-vector.ai

Comment: If you have found the answer below to have answered your question please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer.  If the answers do not answer your question please make an [edit] seeking clarity.

Answer (score 1):

to find the right scaling factor use this formula

```
current width = 100%
desired width = ? 

176 px -> 100%
768 px -> ?

? = 768*100/176 = 436.3636364%
```

doing the same for the height, it shows it will not be 100% proportional, just close to it.

```
? = 235*100/1024= 435.7446809%
```

so, select the whole group and scale Uniformly by 436.3636364% to keep proportions, or by both width x height, to get the measurements you're after.